# Reaction of hydrogen peroxide with sodium carbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium

In my book the following acid base reaction is written:

$$\ce{H2O2 + Na2CO3 -> Na2O2 + H2O + CO2}$$

But I found that the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value of $\ce{H2CO3}$ is less than the one for $\ce{H2O2},$ which means $\ce{H2CO3}$ is more acidic than $\ce{H2O2}.$

As $\ce{H2CO3}$ is getting formed as the product (and then decomposing to give $\ce{CO2}$), shouldn't the reverse reaction be more favourable due to greater acidity of $\ce{H2CO3}$ and the above reaction not happen significantly?

Is $\ce{H2CO3}$ maybe getting decomposed as soon as it forms allowing this reaction to occur?

Comment: Please visit [this page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [this one](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reaction is wrong and incorrect. Which textbook is teaching this non-sense?

Comment: Just some local book. So if this reaction doesn't occur, is the reverse reaction true? Do we get sodium carbonate and hydrogen peroxide by mixing carbonic acid with sodium peroxide?

Comment: Note that carbonic acid is not an ordinary reagent, it does not exist as such. You cannot buy it. So the terminology that mixing carbonic acid with something is incorrect. Yes, the opposite may be likely if you understand that carbonic acid is nothing but carbon dioxide dissolved in water (like Sprite or Coke)

Answer (score 1):

The impossibility of a reaction producing simultaneously $\ce{Na_2O_2, H_2O_2}$ and $\ce{CO_2}$ can be proved by the following arguments, drawn from the Merck Index, under the reference "$8728$. Sodium Peroxide".

1) $\ce{Na_2O_2}$ is produced by burning metallic sodium in a current of air, from which carbon dioxide has been removed.

2) $\ce{Na_2O_2}$ reacts so easily with $\ce{CO_2}$ that it is used for rendering air charged with $\ce{CO_2}$ respirable as in submarines and diving bells.

3) $\ce{Na_2O_2}$ absorbs water from the air forming sodium hydroxyde and hydrogen peroxide, the latter quickly decomposed into Oxygen and water.

Ref.: Maryadele O'Neil, Ann Smith, et al., The Merck Index, An Encyclopedia of Chemicals, 13th Ed. 2001, Merck & Co Inc., Whitehouse Station, NJ, USA.